# Is there an English translation of Laumon's proof of geometric Langlands for $\mathbb{G}_m$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, langlands-conjectures

I'd like a detailed proof in English of Laumon's proof that the two Fourier-Mukai transforms taking the derived category of quasicoherent sheaves on $\mathbb{G}_m$-local systems of a curve $X$ to the derived category of $D$-modules on $Bun_{\mathbb{G}_m}(X)$ are mutually inverse.

Laumon's original (unpublished) paper, *Transformation de Fourier généralisée* is on the arXiv: [alg-geom/9603004](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9603004), but I'd ideally like an English translation, or at least an expository paper in English.

Comment: Easy to find, but even easier when one is provided a title or other reference.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Edited

Answer (score 6):

I would be surprised if there is a translation of Laumon. However, you can look the beginning section of Schnell's *Holonomic D-modules on abelian varieties* for a summary of some of Laumon's results.